# How can I force my label to align to the left?

Tags: css, text-align

I want to give my text-field a label, that should be aligned to the left:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

  <table style="width:100%; height:100%">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td style="padding:15px" valign="top">
          <div class="tab-content product_single">
            <section class="content-header" style="margin-bottom:20px">
              <h1 style="float:left;margin-bottom:30px">New Entry</h1>
            </section>
            <section class="content">
              <div class="form-group">
                <form name="form" method="post">
                <div id="form"><div><label for="form_username" class="required">Username</label><input id="form_username" name="form[username]" required="required" class="form-control" type="text"></div><div><label for="form_email" class="required">Email</label><input id="form_email" name="form[email]" required="required" class="form-control" type="text"></div><div><button type="button" id="form_cancel" name="form[cancel]" class="form-btn btn btn-default pull-right close_sidebar close_h">Cancel</button></div><div><button type="submit" id="form_save" name="form[save]" class="form-btn btn btn-info pull-right" style="margin-right:5px">Save</button></div><input id="form__token" name="form[_token]" value="" type="hidden"></div>
                </form>
              </div>
            </section>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Because of some styles in my application, somehow my first label always sticks to the middle, and I cannot figure out in any style, what is the reason for this. So I try everything like `text-align:left` or `text-align:left!important`, but whatever I do, it just sticks to the center.

[image]

Comment: in the snippet is fine

Comment: Then create a snippet demonstrating the issue... Inspect the element and check which style of yours causes the issue.

Comment: @Jarla But what's the point of the demo if it doesn't reproduce the problem?

Comment: You should use the developer tools (press F12 on most browser) to get the styles applied to the element. Try to get also the reason why this not happens to the email label (there is a difference).

Comment: Its your `float:left;` on the h1 tag that causes this issue on your 'reproduce' sample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to clear the float on your heading - not sure why you have floated it.  Also do not use tables for layout - it will negate the use of bootstrap and is semantically incorrect

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="tab-content product_single">
  <section class="content-header" style="margin-bottom:20px">
    <h1 style="float:left;margin-bottom:30px">New Entry</h1>
  </section>
  

  <section class="content" style="clear:left">  <!-- I have added this style attribute or you could just remove the float from the heading -->
  
  
    <div class="form-group">
      <form name="form" method="post">
        <div id="form">
          <div><label for="form_username" class="required">Username</label><input id="form_username" name="form[username]" required="required" class="form-control" type="text"></div>
          <div><label for="form_email" class="required">Email</label><input id="form_email" name="form[email]" required="required" class="form-control" type="text"></div>
          <div><button type="button" id="form_cancel" name="form[cancel]" class="form-btn btn btn-default pull-right close_sidebar close_h">Cancel</button></div>
          <div><button type="submit" id="form_save" name="form[save]" class="form-btn btn btn-info pull-right" style="margin-right:5px">Save</button></div><input id="form__token" name="form[_token]" value="" type="hidden"></div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```